# Mockito / PowerMock compability issue

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am getting a following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.Mockito.framework()Lorg/mockito/MockitoFramework
```

when trying to run JUnit tests ever since i switched Mockito version from 1.10.19 to 3.1.0 and PowerMock version 1.7.4 to 2.0.4.

I also tried using Mockito version 2.2.28 wtih PowerMock version 2.0.4, got the same error.

In every class i have following annotations, maybe that could help you:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Some.class)
```

Comment: Did you try removing the Mockito dependencies and letting PowerMock resolve them?

Comment: Are you able to provide the source of the test and the full stack trace?

Comment: @Villat i tried that already, no luck.

Comment: @JamesWilson unfortunately i can't

Comment: What dependencies did you try exactly? Also check [the compatiblity list](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions). For the latest version of powermockito you want to test the version it was build against. -- (powermockito 2.0.4 and mockito 2.2.28 won't work together)

Comment: @second i also tried mockito 3.1.0 with powermock 2.0.4. That should work according to the compability list right?

Comment: At least it should not give you the error you are facing (assuming you tried `powermock-module-junit4`+ `powermock-api-mockito2` + `mockito-core`), but based on some question I have been answered certain things seem to be broken if you use a `mockito` version newer than `2.28.2` (the one they build `2.0.4` against).

Comment: @second do you suggest i should use mockito version 2.28.2 then? That one must work with powermock 2.0.4 right?

Comment: You should try it to figure out what your real problem is. If it still does not work it probably has something to do with your depency management system. If it does work you can try newer versions and see whether some tests that worked before are now broken.

Comment: Yup, you were right. Older version of mockito was inherited from a parent pom file, but even though i excluded mockito-core from that jar file, powermock still used that old version of mockito-core and not the new one. So i also excluded mockito-core from powermock too and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error with help from @second:

> You should try it to figure out what your real problem is. If it still does not work it probably has something to do with your depency management system. If it does work you can try newer versions and see whether some tests that worked before are now broken

And the mistake:

> Yup, you were right. Older version of mockito was inherited from a parent pom file, but even though i excluded mockito-core from that jar file, powermock still used that old version of mockito-core and not the new one. So i also excluded mockito-core from powermock too and now it works